# Is there any way to stop creaks and lifting on a floating floor over concrete?

Tags: flooring, engineered-flooring

I recently had much of the flooring in my apartment redone as part of a broader renovation project. I had engineered hardwood installed over a subfloor that's cast concrete. My architects specified that the flooring should be installed floating, which was compatible with the manufacturer's recommendations for this particular product.

So there are (as far as I'm aware) no fasteners and is no glue to bond the finish flooring to the subfloor.

For the most part it's great. But now that I've been living with it for about a year, there are a few spots where it creaks or very slightly lifts as you walk over it.

I suspect this is due to slight imperfections in the floor level that weren't (and probably should have been) addressed before the flooring was installed.

Is there any way to address this problem without taking all the flooring out and fixing the underlying level? Or indeed, is this something that may go away as the flooring slowly "molds" to the slight imperfections as furniture and people weigh it down?

Comment: I'm no expert, but AIUI, the flooring won't "mold" to the dips, it'll crack and break. I'd suggest pulling up the flooring & fixing the smoothness of it _before_ it breaks on you.

Comment: Unless it's got really big height differential, I highly doubt engineered hardwood will break.  It's not tile.

Comment: you can drill a hole in the flooring and inject a filler (caulk, epoxy, etc) to fill the void and then patch the hole.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MGA3cyLJBc

Comment: Yes, fortunately the deflection is very subtle. I'm not really worried about damage. But it's enough it makes annoying noises (clicking, squeaking), which is my main concern.

Answer (score 1):

Even engineered wood settles and conforms over time. You could accelerate this by weighting it with something like sand bags for a few days to weeks. Depending on the nature of the lump it'll either bend or dent, which should reduce noise.

A little moisture would help with this. You wouldn't have as much success in a very dry situation. Wait for summer or run a vaporizer for a few days first.